# Couchbase ViewQuery array range doesn't work (node.js sdk)

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have an express app with couchbase as the DB and have an express router like this:

```
router.get('/:key', function(req, res, next){
  var champId = req.params.key;
  var startKey = [champId, 0, false];
  var endKey = [champId, 100000, true];
  var input = {
    'bucket' : dbbucket,
    'document' : dbdocument,
    'view' : dbview,
    'viewStartKey' : startKey,
    'viewEndKey' : endKey,
    'inclusiveEnd' : true,
    'groupLevel' : 3
  };

  dbconnect.dbQuery(input, function(dbError){
    res.status(500).send('Could not retrieve the requested data');
  }, function(results) {
    res.status(200).send(results);
  });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  var input = {
    'bucket' : dbbucket,
    'document' : dbdocument,
    'view' : dbview,
    'groupLevel' : 3
  };

  dbconnect.dbQuery(input, function(dbError){
    res.status(500).send('Could not retrieve the requested data');
  }, function(results) {
    res.status(200).send(results);
  });
});
```

My dbQuery method is:

```
function queryExecuter (input, error, callback){
  var constructedQuery = queryConstructor(input.document, input.view);
  if(input.viewKey){
    constructedQuery = constructedQuery.key(input.viewKey);
  }
  if(input.viewStartKey && input.viewEndKey && input.inclusiveEnd){
    constructedQuery = constructedQuery.range(input.viewStartKey, input.viewEndKey, input.inclusiveEnd);
  }
  if(input.groupLevel){
    constructedQuery = constructedQuery.group_level(input.groupLevel);
  }
  input.bucket.query(constructedQuery, function(dbError, results) {
    if(dbError) {
      error(dbError);
      return;
    }
    callback(results);
  });
}
```

When I try to run without startKey and endKey, data returns fine but when I run with startKey and endKey, I get an empty array as a response (I should be getting 159 records as that's the amount of data I get when I run without startKey and endKey, also when I query the bucket with the same startKey and endKey from couchbase console, that's what I get). I'm using nodejs version 4.2.1 and couchbase version 4.1.0. I also tried using startKey.toString() and endKey.toString(). Still the same result.

Comment: Before entering your `dbconnect.dbQuery` methods, can you validate that the `input` variables contain what you'd expect via a `console.log`?  It would also be helpful to see some example data and a completed example request to go with it.  Will help rule out the point of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I hit the /:key route, the startKey and endKey that I generate would be [ '1', 0, false] and [ '1', 10000, true] instead of [ 1, 0, false] and [ 1, 10000, true].

Note to all people who try to work with such routes: ALWAYS use parseInt(req.params.key).

The working piece of code:

```
router.get('/:key', function(req, res, next){
  var champId = req.params.key;
  var champIdInt = parseInt(champId);
  var startKey = [champIdInt, 0, false];
  var endKey = [champIdInt, 100000, true];
  var input = {
    'bucket' : dbbucket,
    'document' : dbdocument,
    'view' : dbview,
    'viewStartKey' : startKey,
    'viewEndKey' : endKey,
    'inclusiveEnd' : true,
    'groupLevel' : 3
  };

  dbconnect.dbQuery(input, function(dbError){
    res.status(500).send('Could not retrieve the requested data');
  }, function(results) {
    res.status(200).send(results);
  });
});
```